# What $x$ for this equation $2\cos x(\cos x - \sin x) + \tan^2 x < \sec^2 x$ .

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

> For $0<x<\pi$. If ${x||R a<x<b} $ is the solution for $2\cos x(\cos x - \sin x) + \tan^2 x < \sec^2 x $. What is $b - a?$

$2\cos x(\cos x - \sin x) + \tan^2 x < sec^2 x $
$2\cos^2 x - 2 \cos x \sin x - 1 < 0$

$\cos 2x < \sin 2x$

What $x$ for this equation?

When $\pi/6 < x < \pi/2$ i think $\cos 2x < \sin 2x$.

Answer (score 1):

Now, $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-2x\right)<0,$$ which gives
$$2\pi k<2x-\frac{\pi}{4}<\pi+2\pi k,$$ where $k\in\mathbb Z,$ which with $0<x<\pi$ gives $$\frac{\pi}{8}<x<\frac{5\pi}{8}.$$
Also, we know that $x\neq\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: $\pi + 2\pi k < \frac{\pi}{4} - 2x < 2\pi k$ why does it dont work?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Because $\pi<0$ is wrong. Maybe did you mean $-\pi+2\pi k<\frac{\pi}{4}-2x<2\pi k$? If so, then it's the same.

Comment: Why $-\pi$ not $ \pi$

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Because $\sin\alpha<0$ for $-\pi+2\pi k<\alpha<2\pi k$, $k\in\mathbb Z$. Also, your writing gives $\pi<0$. See please better my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos2x<\sin2x\iff\sqrt2\cos\left(2x+\dfrac\pi4\right)<0$$

$$\implies2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2<2x+\dfrac\pi4<2m\pi+\pi+\dfrac\pi2$$ where $m$ is any integer